# Sending sms message if the pc state is shutdown or restarted

Tags: c#, vb.net, sms

In my company there is a console app running on a windows environment serve/pc. My problem is when this Server shuts down or restarted by other people this app will be closed and have to restart the app manually for this I have to issue commands on it to start running.
and another problem is I would not know if the server state just restarted or shuts down.
    I have this idea that i will build an app that would send me a sms message to my phone and alert me that this server is down or just restarted in .net vb/c#. honestly, I don't know where to start I tried to search it on the internet but found nothing. If you can help me where to start I'll appreciate it much and i will post here the development stage of this app.

thanks.

Comment: What I would do is make a Windows Service, and use msconfig to start the application automatically upon the system boot.  That is just a general idea.

Comment: @david Venegoni that would be great if that would be the case but the problem is even if I will start it automatically using your advice,the app still will not run if I don't issue those commands on the console.

Comment: Okay, I will try some things out and see if I can find a suitable answer for you.

Comment: What VS and framework are you using?

Comment: vs 2010 4 or 3.5 will do

Comment: Okay, thanks for the information, I will work on finding a suitable solution tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for the delay on an answer.  Anyway, I have found out that there is no way to differentiate between a system shut down and a system restart.  But in any case, I think your best approach is to the use the SystemEvents.SessionEnding and/or SystemEvents.SessionEnded events to capture the system/server's shutdown.  The easiest way to do this would be to use a Windows Service and register these events, like so:

```
public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase
{
    public Service1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        /* Choose one or both of these to register for */
        SystemEvents.SessionEnding += OnSessionEnding; // Register with session ending event
        SystemEvents.SessionEnded += OnSessionEnded;   // Register with session ended event

    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        /* Static events, so MUST deregister from them */
        SystemEvents.SessionEnding -= OnSessionEnding;
        SystemEvents.SessionEnded -= OnSessionEnded;
    }

    protected static void OnSessionEnding(Object sender, SessionEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        /* I suggest using SchwabenCode.EasySmtp as it is very easy to use and implements the IDisposable interface.  If that is not an option, than simply use SmtpClient class */
        if (e.Reason == SessionEndReasons.SystemShutdown)
        {
            // Send SMS message to yourself notifying shutdown is occurring on server
        }
    }

    protected static void OnSessionEnded(Object sender, SessionEndedEventArgs e)
    {
        /* I suggest using SchwabenCode.EasySmtp as it is very easy to use and implements the IDisposable interface.  If that is not an option, than simply use SmtpClient class */
        if (e.Reason == SessionEndReasons.SystemShutdown)
        {
            // Send SMS message to yourself notifying shutdown is occurring on server
        }
    }
}
```

I hope that helps you get things started!  Here is a enum and its extensions that I have used in the past for sending SMS messages:

```
/// <summary>   Values that represent various carriers. </summary>
[Serializable]
public enum Carrier
{
    None = 0,
    Alltel = 1,
    Att = 2,
    BoostMobile = 3,
    Sprint = 4,
    Tmobile = 5,
    UsCellular = 6,
    Verizon = 7,
    VirginMobile = 8
}

/// <summary>   Carrier extensions. </summary>
public static class CarrierExtensions
{
    /// <summary>   Gets the email to SMS gateway for the specified carrier. </summary>
    /// <param name="carrier">  The carrier to get the gateway for.</param>
    /// <returns>   The email to SMS gateway. </returns>
    public static String GetGateway(this Carrier carrier)
    {
        switch (carrier)
        {
            case Carrier.Alltel:
                return "@message.alltel.com";
            case Carrier.Att:
                return "@txt.att.net";
            case Carrier.BoostMobile:
                return "@myboostmobile.com";
            case Carrier.Sprint:
                return "@messaging.sprintpcs.com";
            case Carrier.Tmobile:
                return "@tmomail.net";
            case Carrier.UsCellular:
                return "@email.uscc.net";
            case Carrier.Verizon:
                return "@vtext.com";
            case Carrier.VirginMobile:
                return "@vmobl.com";
        }
        return String.Empty;
    }

    /// <summary>   Formats the phone number with the appropriate email to SMS gateway. </summary>
    /// <param name="carrier">      The carrier to get the gateway for.</param>
    /// <param name="phoneNumber">  The phone number.</param>
    /// <returns>   The formatted phone number. </returns>
    public static String FormatPhoneNumber(this Carrier carrier, String phoneNumber)
    {
        return String.Format("{0}{1}", phoneNumber, carrier.GetGateway());
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks i will take a look at this one..will update you after i done testing..thanks a lot.this is a great help

Comment: To send the SMS, you could also look at Twilio (whom I work for...), so you don't have to worry about different Carrier etc. There is a quickstart for sending SMS in C# here: https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/csharp/sms/sending-via-rest

Comment: @xmjw Hi I tried the twilio and embed the code on david's windows service code. it didn't send a sms message to me

Comment: @xmjw I know this was 1 year ago. sorry I forgot to update this one

Comment: @androidz Hm. I've moved on from Twilio, but you might want to contact help@twilio.com - they can help get your sorted.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest would be to place the app in the startup folder:

- for individual users: C:\Users[username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup
- for all users: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup

But a better solution is to use the windows Task Scheduler and create a task to run the application on startup. [Here is a link to an example using the scheduler](http://forum.wegotserved.com/index.php/tutorials/article/55-how-to-automatically-start-program-when-server-boots/).